# PVS-Studio fails to analyse https://github.com/viva64/pvs-studio-cmake-examples/tree/master/example-1

Tags: cmake, pvs-studio

I pulled down example-1 and generated a CMake project for it using:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <source-dir>
```

When I built the project I saw the following ouput:

```
[ 40%] Built target pvs-studio-cmake-example-1
[ 60%] Analyzing CXX file main.cpp
Your license will expire in 0 days. Contact us at support@viva64.com.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1.analyze.dir/build.make:73: PVS- 
Studio/main.cpp.plog] Error 2
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'PVS-Studio/main.cpp.plog'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: 
CMakeFiles/example1.analyze.dir/all] Error 2
```

make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2

I am using Fedora 28.

```
gcc (GCC) 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)
```

Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: This? > Your license will expire in 0 days. Contact us at support@viva64.com.

Comment: @arrowd: I am using the free version (https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0457/#ID0E4VAE). So I do not need a license.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in the release version of PVS-Studio, please try a beta version from here: [https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio-download-beta](https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio-download-beta/). This bug should be fixed in this beta.

Comment: OK. Will do. Thanks